# Bing maps using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, bing

I am new to this OpenLayers API , I have got an assignment to make a bing map using openlayers and place pointers on it, I am not able to find any website for starters on openlayers using bing, please can someone provide me with a proper link where to find the tutorials for "beginners"

Answer (score 0):

The openlayers examples page https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/ (other example pages for 3.x versions are no longer available) and the API docs should provide more then enough information. If you're a complete beginner a very good tutorial for openlayers 3 can be found at, http://christopherjennison.com/openlayers3-quickstart-tutorial/